# How to make web page auto scroll for given period of time?

Tags: html, autoscroll

I have written a html code 
Which displays the lyrics of the song HELLO by ADELE.
I have also added the AUDIO FILE to it.
I want the page to auto scroll for the duration of the song automatically when I hit the play button.
The whole lyrics is in only one division of the body.
How to set the time for this?
Is this possible in html?

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
$('html, body').animate({
  scrollTop: $(document).height()
}, 100000);
```

You can replace 100000 with the duration of the song.